# GET запрос python не выдает нужной информации

Tags: python, bs4, aiohttp, requests-html

Пытаюсь спарсить страницу сайта [https://www.vinted.pl/ubrania?catalog[]=1904&order=newest_first](https://www.vinted.pl/ubrania?catalog%5B%5D=1904&order=newest_first), нужно получить ссылку на автора объявления, пытался отправить запрос при помощи aiohttp и requests_html с javascript рендером, однако успеха нет никакого. После подставил заголовки headers, однако всё по прежнему также, сайт по html прост.

Текущий код:

```
from asyncio import run, create_task, gather
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
# from aiohttp import ClientSession
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

global headers
headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'cookie': '''anon_id=aefcc3e2-e53e-4918-ac95-21367d86d4c0; v_sid=3e70eb9c6a611d085649f28a23739101; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; domain_selected=true; __cf_bm=w_sIikc5Z8.Vihn_gmR.BAZnyUd335EhmFqU4bmZYus-1642438311-0-AYCHF/Slflz+tWDQjDowF2mrnxhTuhvhItk5Ap2aLHX2i5Mla8r39tiqRFCcT0ZSgYbdorFax4Y0JVg2NteyGF++HIMUM3RuFC6vO+2x9IgTZVRBy/luseM4OC5dgHnHuFv1ZwsJCEA4uSd2Kfd/SrJE4FwTnL8RDOrXGo8goT0QEH49ojTi5FoKehpCf/hRpA==; _vinted_pl_session=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--f36190a09d4bb13764a1c7472d36d57c0ed50ad0; _dd_s=rum=0&expire=1642439716050; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2022-01-17T17:00:16.052Z; eupubconsent-v2=CPS-EFePS-EFeAcABBENB-CsAP_AAAAAAChQIXtf_X__b3_j-_59f_t0eY1P9_7_v-0zjhfdt-8N2f_X_L8X42M7vF36pq4KuR4Eu3LBIQVlHOHcTUmw6okVrzPsbk2cr7NKJ7PEmnMbO2dYGH9_n93TuZKY7______z_v-v_v____f_7-3_3__5_3---_e_V_99zLv9____39nP___9v-_8CAAAAcJACABoAvMVABAXmMgAgLzHQAwAaABmAXmQgAgBmJQAgAzALzKQAwAaABmAXmAA.f_gAAAAAAAAA; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=47633054983887; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Mon+Jan+17+2022+20%3A00%3A16+GMT%2B0300+(%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)&version=6.25.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=02515bd0-e738-406f-9f59-c5c755f10c37&interactionCount=2&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CSTACK42%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false''',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.62'
}


async def first_request():
    global headers
    asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
    response = await asession.get('https://www.vinted.pl/ubrania?catalog[]=1904&order=newest_first', headers=headers)
    await response.html.arender()
    # print(response.html.html)
    o_html = BS(response.html.html, 'lxml')
    print(o_html.find('div', class_ = 'body-content').find('div', class_ = 'feed-grid'))
    # with open("test.html", "wb") as file:
    #     file.write(await response.read())
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(first_request())
```

Желаемый результат это получить ссылку на аккаунт автора объявления, скриншот внизу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дмнамический свйт BeautifulSoup здесь безсилен селениум тебе в помощь

Comment: Что то вы намудрили с рендером страницы. Там все данные лежат в исходной html в виде одного большого json. Берете текст этого скрипта и парсите его как обычный json. Никакой javascript выполнять на странице не надо. Сделайте запрос просто страницы, посмотрите вернул ли сайт нормальный текст, если вернул, то берете из него `script[data-js-react-on-rails-store="MainStore"]` (обращение в css нотации)

Comment: Для теста прямо в консоли сайта `JSON.parse($('script[data-js-react-on-rails-store="MainStore"]').text())['items']['catalogItems']['byId']`. Указанный блок присутствует в исходной html, никакого подтягивания данных на более поздней стадии на сайте нет. При смене разделов происходит полная перегрузка

Comment: Mike, спасибо за ваши ответы. Я и вправду удивлён, что так просто пропустил данные json мимо. Однако это не всё что мне было нужно, сейчас моя задача получить данные о пользователе с страницы - https://www.vinted.pl/member/1302589-karolina291099 - от себя был бы очень рад если бы вы помогли мне найти их, так как сам я ещё не нашёл. Если что о данных пользователя имею ввиду количество комментариев и объявлений. Заранее спасибо, с уважением Максим, надеюсь вы поможете и в этот раз)